# Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

Hi i am trying to capture screenshoot, put it into PDF and download with ReactJS Application.
I've created method that after click should generate PDF:

```
generatePDF = () => {
    const printArea = document.getElementById("field")
    html2canvas(printArea).then(canvas => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 200, 200);
      pdf.save("download.pdf");

    })
  }
```

It returns me an error: "Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData "

This is my render method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="nav"></div>
        <div className="field" id="field">
          {
            this.createTables()
          }
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.generatePDF} style={{ marginTop: 500 }}>Generate PDF</button>
      </div>

    )
  }
```

I was checking, generatePDF properly gives me div, problem appears on screen when addImage is executing.

Comment: The problem is probably caused because `imageData` contains the `data:` prefix, you can pass the `canvas` element to `addImage`, eg: `pdf.addImage(canvas, , 'PNG', 0, 0, 200, 200)`

Comment: It shows me the same error, doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting the same error ? The documentation mentions that the first argument to [addImage(..)](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage) can be a `HTMLCanvasElement`.

Comment: It's the problem with position absolute, html2canvas has issues when element is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encourage you to use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead of document.getElementById("field")

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because, all elements in div have set position absolute, so elements was blank. I changed to static and it works perfectly.